# Natural Numbers Equation

Tags: problem-solving, natural-numbers

I am trying to find the $(k_1,k_2,...,k_N)$ tuples solutions to an all natural numbers equation in the following form :

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$, $N\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $n_i\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\leq n$ for $i=1..N$

$n=\sum_{i=1}^Nk_in_i$ with $k_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for $i=1...N$.

From the solutions, I am trying to find the "biggest" one. I am having trouble explaining the ordering I'm looking for mathematically but an example should do it:

$(4,1,2)>(4,0,1)>(2,58,99)$

Basically the elements are compared in order, and if there is a tie, we check the next ones, and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to formulate this problem in a cleaner way, and a way to solve such equations ?

What I am currently trying is to do a step by step euclidean division, starting by the first $n_i$ and so on. I may however get a remainder at the end, while different choices (for instance lower quotients at some steps) could have resulted in a $0$ remainder at the end.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [lexicographically greatest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) solution. Is this a problem from some programming contest or part of a larger problem you're trying to solve? Needing to solve one particular instance of the problem is different from needing to solve many instances subject in automated fashion in limited amount of time.

Comment: It is part of a larger problem which is programming related. The Lexicographical order applies for when I have actually found the solutions right ?